# "Why shouldn't" or "Why wouldn't" in a question

Tags: word-choice, questions

I want to say that someone is surprised and questions why juice is not that healthy (because of sugar).

So I would let the person say "Why shouldn’t juice be healthy?“ or "Why wouldn’t juice be healthy?“

What do you think is better?

I would tend to "wouldn't“ but I’m no native speaker.

Comment: _Wouldn't_ would be more natural in this context.

Comment: Note that we do not use that style of quotation marks in English. We would write "wouldn't".

Answer (score 1):

In this example, "*wouldn't*" makes the most sense.

Remember:

- "Should" pertains to *obligation*, or what ought to happen
- "Would" pertains to *possibility*.

Your dialogue is expressing surprise at the *possibility* that juice may not be healthy, and the expected response would be facts to support that possibility.

Asking why something '*shouldn't*' be the case would invite a response containing reasons why something ought not be the case. It can also be used rhetorically - for example, if someone asked "*why shouldn't dessert be healthy?*", it comes from the viewpoint that desserts are generally *not* healthy, but and invites anyone to challenge the idea that they could be made healthy.